# Is a label for an hidden field 508 compliant?

Tags: html, struts2, accessibility, w3c-validation, section508

I have the following Struts2 code which generates a list of shippers.  It only shows after the user choses the type of shipment (the `hidden` class is removed by JavaScript).

```
<div class ="showIfNotOther hidden">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12  rowsecthead" id="shipperInfoHeader"><s:text name="shipperInfo"/></div>
</div>
<s:iterator value="chosenShipperViewList" status="status">
    <div class="row small-line-height">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12 "><label for='<s:property value="%{'deleteShipper'+#status.index}" />' class="pull-right"><s:text name="deleteShipperInfo"></s:text>:</label></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 text-left">
            <s:url var="deleteLink" action="shipment_deleteShipperFromChosenShipperViewList"></s:url>
            <s:a id="%{'deleteShipper'+#status.index}" href="%{deleteLink}"> <img   src="/llr/theme/delete.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Map Red X" ></s:a>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>                
</s:iterator>
```

The Struts2 code generates the following HTML which has each "Delete Shipper Info:" label associated with each `<a>` element by an id (`deleteShipper0`, `deleteShipper1`, etc.) which is what I understand is required to be [508 compliant](http://www.508checker.com/what-is-508-compliance).

```
<div class ="showIfNotOther hidden">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12  rowsecthead" id="shipperInfoHeader">Shipper Information</div>
</div>
<div class="row small-line-height">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12 "><label for='deleteShipper0' class="pull-right">Delete Shipper Info:</label></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 text-left">
        <a id="deleteShipper0" href="/llr/shipment_deleteShipperFromChosenShipperViewList.action?organizationName=Mercy"><img   src="/llr/theme/delete.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Map Red X" ></a>
    </div>
    <hr>
</div>                
<div class="row small-line-height">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12 "><label for='deleteShipper1' class="pull-right">Delete Shipper Info:</label></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 text-left">
        <a id="deleteShipper1" href="/llr/shipment_deleteShipperFromChosenShipperViewList.action?organizationName=Nuclear"><img src="/llr/theme/delete.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Map Red X" ></a>
    </div>
    <hr>
</div>
```

When I put the HTML in the [*W3C Markup Validation Service*](https://validator.w3.org/) I get the error

> The `for` attribute of the label element must refer to a non-hidden form control.

Is the HTML really not compliant (and if it isn't, how do I fix it), or is this just a bug in the *W3C Markup Validation Service*?

Comment: Try scanning your site with the 508 checker instead that with the plain html checker: http://www.508checker.com/

Comment: My code is on a local host so I assume I need to deploy the code before I can use the site you suggested.  Also, the code in question only shows up after you add some shippers.  I don't see how I can pass an url which will show the code.

Comment: You could add shippers, dump the DOM and publish a static .html page, then validate that. BUT it's faster with this: https://www.totalvalidator.com/tools/index.html (not sure if it allows direct input validation but it's a desktop app so I guess it *should*)

Comment: I assume this is widely used so it is safe to download?

Comment: Mr. Safe is dead... :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As defined by the [W3 definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/label.html) of a `label`:

> The label element represents a caption for a **form control**.

You are currently using a `label` tag for a link, not for a form control, which is your first error.

And yes, it is right:

> The `for` attribute of the label element must refer to a non-hidden form control.

When navigating with a screenreader you have to be able to go from the label to the form control. But in your case, it seems that both your label and your future form control (once you will have replaced the link with a form control) will be in the same hidden `div`. So you won't have to care about such remark.

But I think that using a form control will remove this comment from the W3 validator as it does not handle CSS.

Comment: I don't know how to make the code work with a form control instead of a link.  So should I just use plain text to caption my link?

Comment: I'm not sure my question was clear.  If I use plain text to caption my link will it be 508 compliant?  Does the link by itself provide enough information for screen readers?  Thanks!